# Are there any open source packages for detetcting nouns, verbs etc in a sentence on iOS?

Tags: ios, nlp

So, given a sentence such as "The quick brown fox called Jerry jumped over the lazy dog", I'd like to be able call a function in iOS that would allow me to identify the nouns, verbs, adverbs etc programmatically.

Does such a package exist? The ones I have found seem to be for other platforms (WordNet, openNLP etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`NSLinguisticTagger`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSLinguisticTagger) is available in iOS 5+.

Comment: Thank you. This looks perfect for my needs. Do you have any experience of its run time performance because NLP is NP hard? (http://www.ucl.ac.uk/psychlangsci/research/linguistics/publications/wpl/92papers/UCLWPL4_18_van_de_Koot)